# Execution of Selenium project on Weblogic server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to build a selenium project for testing(Sanity testing) the one of the client applications. 
Plan is to create a Dynamic Web Project and deploy this selenium project on the Server. So that who ever wants to run a test case or smoke test can launch it with the help of UI and gets it executed on their machine. (Just like how the normal J2EE Web Applications will work) 
I found it might be bit complex. Because from Server, a request has to be sent to client browser and then the browser has to be launched on the client machine (like normal WebDriver scenario in local machine) and then run the test. 
Can someone please suggest me whether this is doable or not? If yes, please help me with the approach.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: how about when user requests to run tests you run it as headless browser and then at then end just send reports to him?

Comment: yup this approach is also fine!!! Please suggest if it can be done? (This is mainly for a Sanity test of a application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: Yes it can be done. 
 Next step: 
 1. Please go ahead making changes to your project to use headless browsers 
 2. Once its run then email or FTP the reports to users Temp directory.. All the Best!!!

Comment: Thanks for the idea!! It helped!!